# how does whatsapp get list of all registered contacts so fast?

Tags: android

I am trying to make an app like Whatsapp where I need to get a list of all registered contacts.
how to check if my contact is registered with my app or not.
let's suppose my phone has 800 contacts and if send these contacts to server and crosscheck with millions of users saved in a database then it might take 1-2minute.How does WhatsApp does it so fast.

Comment: you can use a lot of filters, (Country, City)
why not filter with starting numbers etc..

Comment: Well, no, it should not take 1-2 minutes. If your server / DB is setup correctly it should much, much less than that.

Comment: what if I have contacts of other countries also?can you please give me schema of DB you are suggesting.